# SQLite management library

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to write a backdoor into my app to access the DB directly so that I can, for example, delete unwanted rows created during development or modify values for testing.

It seems there should libraries out there for this but I cannot find any.

If these libraries don't exist, how do you get SQLiteOpenHelper (or whatever) to give the structure of a database (tables and rows)?

Thank you, good people.

Comment: Usually, developers just work with the database (e.g., pull a copy to their development machine). What you are describing sounds like a lot of work for a less-capable solution.

Comment: Pulling + editing in external program + pushing versus working directly through the app? It seems like less work to me but, well, different folks different strokes.

Comment: Writing your own SQLite management UI (either in-app or some sort of browser/desktop app) will take a fair bit of time, versus a second or so per push and pull. Or, buy the Ultimate edition of IntelliJ IDEA 13, which has a built-in SQLite editor. There used to be a SQLite editor in the old Motorola Eclipse add-ons, but those have long been discontinued.

Comment: Yes, the new IDEA. Thanks. That's useful.